# give user defined parameters in 2d array function in C++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

**void dijkstra(int V, int graph[V][V],int a,int b,string city[])**
Getting error in 2D array parameter

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int minValueIndex(vector<int>& value, vector<bool>& processed, int V)
{
    int minimum = INT_MAX;
    int ver;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        if (processed[i] == false && value[i] < minimum) {
            ver = i;
            minimum = value[I];
        }
    }
    return ver;
}

void dijkstra(int V, int graph[][V], int a, int b, string city[])
{
    int parent[V];
    vector<int> value(V, INT_MAX);
    vector<bool> processed(V, false);
    int src = a, d = b;
    parent[src] = -1;
    value[src] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < V - 1; ++i) {
        int index = minValueIndex(value, processed, V); //selectMinIndex
        processed[index] = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < V; ++j) {
                if (graph[index][j] != 0 && processed[j] == false && value[index] != INT_MAX
                    && (value[index] + graph[index][j] < value[j]))
            {
                value[j] = value[index] + graph[index][j];
                parent[j] = index;
            }
        }
    }
    string arr[V];
    int temp = d;
    int count = 0;
    while (d != src) {
        arr[count] = city[parent[d]];
        d = parent[d];
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << arr[i] << "->";
    cout << city[temp];
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Happy Journey!!\n";
}

int main()
{
    int V;
    cout << "Enter Total Cities\n";
    cin >> V;
    string city[V];
    cout << "Enter Cities\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        cin >> city[i];
    cout << "Distance Matrix" << endl;
    int graph[V][V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            cin >> graph[i][j];
    cout << "Enter Source\n";
    string src, des;
    int a, b;
    cin >> src;
    cout << "Enter Destination\n";
    cin >> des;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (city[i] == src)
            a = i;
        if (city[i] == des)
            b = i;
    }
    dijkstra(V, graph, a, b, city);
    return 0;
}
```

How to pass user-defined parameters in a 2D array?? I tried to pass the user-defined parameter but I am getting this error, there is any other method available to pass user-defined parameter in 2S Array

Comment: Variable length arrays (VLA) is a C99 feature, not supported by C++. Your first functions seems to work well with a std::vector, so why not try that in the second case as well? You can do `vector<vector<int>>` to get more than one dimension.

Comment: Okay i will try...